# 555 to drive a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, 555

I wish to drive a MOSFET using a 555. I dont have a driver handy, will it be fine to use a transistor instead?
So the output of a 555, could activate a transistor(as swtich), which allows a source to drive the FET?

Comment: Can you not drive the MOSFET directly with the 555? What MOSFET? How fast do you need to drive it? At what voltage? Your question boils down to basically, "can I use transistors to drive things?", and the answer is "yes", but without more detail, there's not much more of an answer than that.

Comment: Why not drive the MOSFET gate directly from the 555 output? What is the background to this question, what is the transistor intended to help with? (presumably you mean a BJT since a MOSFET is also a transistor)

Comment: A standard 555 can source/sink 200 mA. Are you sure you need more than that?

Comment: The current I wish to pass is 2-3 amps, which is why a transistor is not suitable. I was planning to get a power mosfet, but the specs say, they need a high current density to switch.

Comment: Please, tell us more info about your circuit. Switching frequency, voltage you need to switch, is a low-side MOSFET satisfactory?

Comment: A MOSFET like the IRLML2502 will comfortably handle 2-3 Amperes, and is easily switchable directly from the 555 output, and with voltages as low as 3 Volts or lower. No additional drive BJT required.

Answer (score 12):

The [555](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm555) output can Source or Sink 200 mA so unless you want to drive the mosfet in high frequencies it will be more than enough. A single transistor is probably going to drive the mosfet worse than the 555 itself

[image]

If you are need to use a driver between the mosfet and 555 then you are better off with a push-pull (totem pole) driver configuration that can sink/source current equally strong in order to turn on/off the mosfet quickly (again only if needed)

[image]

or even better with a dedicated mosfet driver like  [TC4426/27/28](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001422F.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions! What would you define high frequencies?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

[image: https://arduinodiy.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/fet2.gif]

Just hook up the outgoing end of R2 (where it says "To Arduino") to your 555 output. Note that this circuit is inverted - the load will be ON when the 555 input is LOW. If that is a problem, just put a inverter (74HC04 or similar) in between your 555 output and R2.

If you have what's known as a "logic level MOSFET", you don't need the NPN transistor because logic level MOSFETS can be switched by a lower voltage such as the one provided by the 555. Usually these will have the letter "L" in the component name (for example [IRL540](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91300/91300.pdf)). If it's a logic level MOSFET, it should clearly say that in the datasheet.

If it's not a logic level MOSFET, then you need to use another component to switch a higher voltage (12V in this case). NPN transistors work just fine for this purpose. Regular MOSFETs typically need close to 10-12V to switch on (notice that MOSFETs are voltage-driven and not current-driven).

If you'd like to read more about driving MOSFETs, I'd recomming the following reading:

1. http://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/using-mosfets-with-ttl-levels/
2. http://blog.oscarliang.net/how-to-use-mosfet-beginner-tutorial/
3. http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html

EDIT:

Check out [Switching a current with an NPN transistor and a P-MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53941/switching-a-current-with-an-npn-transistor-and-a-p-mosfet) .